# LSP best practices

Tags: lightning-network, ln-channel-balance-management

The problem of getting *inbound liquidity* on the Lightning Network has given rise to *Lightning Service Providers*, essentially node operators on the Lightning Network, that provide new nodes with inbound liquidity, by opening channels to them.

Since this concept has gained a lot of popularity and there are already multiple companies innovating on this topic, I was wondering whether there is already distilled information about the best practices for operating LSPs out there.

I'm particularly looking for this information:

- Rough estimation about recommended channel size to open to customers (granted, this is heavily dependend on use cases, resp. the usage of an indiviudal user)
- How and when to deal with potential capacity increases/decreases (--> multiple channel support?)
- How to deal with dormant channels (inactive for a prolonged time frame)
- How to deal with channel reserves in a UX-friendly way

Any input is appreciated.